# Customising our chat

Tags: discussion, chat

We have our very own [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2710/computer-science) which everybody should visit from time to time.

We can change many aspects of it, such as title, description and feeds that are pulled and posted.

What do you think should be changed?

Comment: Many sites have given their main chat room a custom title: [The Frying Pan](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16/the-frying-pan), [The Comms Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room), [Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley), …

Comment: @Gilles: That is *so* annoying! Title or description should clearly state which site the (main) chat belongs to; the icons don't quite cut it.

Comment: Oh, so you're proposing not to customize the title then?

Comment: @Gilles: I'm saying the presentation as a whole should make the chat easily to identify as cs.SE main chat. As long as that is guaranteed, I am fine with modifications.

Answer (score 2):

Can we get a distinct favicon from the other cs.SE pages? It doesn't seem to be the usual choice, SO and math.SE have the same favicon in chat. But still, can we?

Related to my answer, but unrelated to the question: can we get to choose a good logo/favicon? I am quite jealous of [math.SE's](http://cdn.sstatic.net/math/img/logo.png?v=123). Will it be possible only once out of public beta?

Comment: Yes. When we graduate, we will get our own style, including a favicon. I don't think it is a particularly good idea to choose a different one for chat; maybe a slight modification? See also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85146/different-favicon-for-chat-window-tab).

Answer (score 1):

hi R am all in favor of encouraging a thriving chat area. feel its significant potential is currently unfortunately underutilized here (same story on TCS.se). it would be extremely cool if some high voted questions gained extended chat dialogue and even collaborative attacks similar to the model of the [polymath project](http://www.siam.org/news/news.php?id=1731).

however, propose a separate chat room other than the main default for the question feeds in contrast to current fmt. as it stands it is impossible to have a train of dialog in the chat room with the interspersed question feed & think it discourages extended dialogue.

am thinking of regularly posting interesting CS links to chat which I run across frequently.

another idea is a ["town hall" mtg](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/901/2011-moderator-elections-town-hall-chat-7pm-utc-on-the-30th) that is announced/scheduled at a particular time that led to a very lively TCS.se dialogue a long time ago.