# CS angle AMA "ask me anything" jun13 Bernardo Meurer

Tags: discussion, chat

earlier this year [Michael Wehar](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/users/27052/michael-wehar) proposed a [CS AMA](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/should-computer-science-meta-start-doing-weekly-amas) "ask me anything" session that had strong support but which has not gone further/ advanced so far beyond conceptual stage. this is to announce not *exactly* that event but one related. on jun13th [Bernardo Meurer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/50764/bernardo-meurer) will host the [Physics AMA](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9898/june-13th-ask-me-anything-feat-bernardo-meurer). he has strong CS interests/ background incl eg knowledge/ inquiry into QM computing and is a fan of the P vs NP question, with many other interests to discuss. he's quite cosmopolitan/ international and already a world traveller, living in Rio de Janeiro and now studying in Lisbon, Portugual.

hope to see CS room denizens drop by, this can function also as a trial case for greater CS involvement and possibly sessions of our "own" in the CS chat room. while not easy to arrange, the [physics AMA](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7783/physics-stack-exchange-ask-me-anything-ama) series has seen a wide range of knowledgeable/ colorful/ accomplished guests, been very popular and well attended. the physics [HBar chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) is very lively even over all SE chat rooms and maybe there is chance for further cross pollination, many regulars have strong CS backgrounds and might find future involvement in the CS chat room worthwhile/ beneficial. this also ties in with the goal of increasing the general CS chat room involvement [expressed](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339/customising-our-chat) early on by mod [Raphael](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/users/98/raphael).

**hope to see you there!**